# Node require relative path in same app

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose I have this directory structure (not real file names):

```
app/
    collections/
        col.one.js
        col.two.js
    models/
        model.js
    main.js
```

Both `col.one.js` and `col.two.js` require `model.js`.  However, neither seems to resolve a relative path.  Both collections contain the line `var model = require('../models/model')` but for some reason, Node continues to look for the file in the collections directory and gives the error `Error: Cannot find module './models/model'`.

Here is model.js

```
var MyModel = module.exports.MyModel = function() {};

MyModel.prototype.myFunc = function(data) {
  this.data = data;
  return this;
};
```

I've tried referencing model.js differently, but nothing seems to work.  I'm new to Node, so I feel like I'm missing something very basic.

Thanks :)

Comment: is `model.js` exporting anything?

Comment: Yes.  I've just edited my post with the contents of model.js

Comment: I'd end up using something like this: `var model = require(process.cwd() + '/app/models/model.js');`  I haven't had much with relative pathing unless I use the root current working directory.

Comment: [This article](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-Where-Does-Node-js-And-Require-Look-For-Modules-.htm) may help you understand a little more.

Comment: @incutonez I went with your process.cwd() suggestion and that helped.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

When `require()`ing other (local) node files, here are two tips:

1. Specify the full file name, including the ".js". In this case, your code should look like: `var model = require('../models/model.js')`
2. A local directory will default to search for `index.js`. So if you renamed `/models/model.js` to `/models/index.js`, you could do this: `var model = require('../models')`, and node will default to looking for `index.js`.

That is just for the `require()` call, so be sure you are exporting, and referencing exports correctly as well.